# When to use Resource Library Contract in JSF 2.2?

Tags: templates, jsf, jsf-2.2

I understand that Resource Library Contract is created to support templating, but even without it, templating can be easily achieved through ui:insert in template.xhtml:

```
<div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content" />
</div>
```

Instead of creating a "contracts" directory, a 'templates' directory can be used under the Web application root.

So, what's the benefit of using contracts?

Comment: I just googled for 'resource library contracts' and found several articles/blogs/`tutorials that explained them. I read about things that are more difficult to achieve with plain 'templating'. Not sure if you read al that, but please do first. Especially the parts about dynamically switching templates.

Comment: It might be the case that for a desktop and mobile application, resource contract library can be used to format the view differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well, you know, both the flows and the resource library contracts were
>   obviously, big-ticket features.  And a resource library contract is
>   really, really powerful if you're in a situation where you want to
>   support both mobile and a desktop client because you can just switch
>   back and forth between a set of templates that you just define.  So
>   that is a really strong feature.
>
> And hopefully, people see that.  But the nice thing about it, it's a
>   stackable feature.  So what that means is you could actually have a
>   resource library contract for a layout, and then a resource library
>   contract on top of that for color styling or something like that.  So
>   you could switch back and forth between -- I'm just using an example,
>   obviously -- a blue and a red styling, and a mobile versus desktop
>   styling.  So that would be four permutations that you would already
>   have.
>
> That's the other thing that jumps out at me because I've -- I'm sure
>   you ran into this as well.  I had clients who basically have a product
>   that they sell, and either it's a hosted product or it's an on premise
>   product.  But either way, each client wants a different look and feel,
>   and different sets of parameters, and things like that.  And you can
>   do a lot of that in the database, but at some point, you want to
>   actually change the templates, and the resource library contracts
>   makes that very easy to use.  So I think that's one of my favorite
>   features, too.

Resource library contracts allow you to have multiple resource libraries which were introduced in `JSF 2.0` where css,js,images and composite components reside in.

1. All template files **must** be named the same
2. all `<ui:inserts name="must have the same attribute value" />`

There are a couple of ways to apply this.

```
-Web Pages/
--contracts/
---resource-1/
-----template.xhtml
-----css/
-----js/
-----img/
---resource-2/
-----template.xhtml
-----css/
-----js/
-----img/
```

**#1: Automatically map contracts on views through URL patterns:**

In the faces-config.xml file

```
<application>

   <contract-mapping>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <contracts>resource-1</contracts>
   </contract-mapping>

   <contract-mapping>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <contracts>resource-2</contracts>
   </contract-mapping>

</application>
```

**#2 Set the contracts con each view:**
*This allows the user to select the Design (Template) to use.*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <f:view contracts="#{templateMB.template}">
        <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>
                    <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{templateMB.tempEvent}"
                                     onchange="submit()">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="..." itemValue="..."/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="resource-1" itemValue="resource-1"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="resource-2" itemValue="resource-2"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**Where the managed bean is:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TemplateMB {

    private String template = "resource-1"; // make default

    public TemplateMB() {
    }

    public void tempEvent(ValueChangeEvent e){
         template = (String) e.getNewValue();
    }

    public String getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple templates and apply them to different pages of the same application, also allow users to select the template that they want to apply.

Good example [Applying JSF 2.2 Resource Library Contracts](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/ResourceLibraryContract/resourceLibraryContract.html)